# truncated integer division removal

Tags: c++, division, long-long

How do T avoid truncated integer division in this code? My sorted array is `1 1 1 1 1 1`, so a[0] = 1 and a[n] should be 1 / 2 = 0.5.

```
int main()
{
    long long n,w;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &w);
    long long arr[2*n];
    for(long long i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
    {
      scanf("%lld", &arr[i]);
    }
    sort(arr,arr+2*n);

    long long a = arr[0];
    long long b = (float)(arr[n]/2); // <--- this part of code
    cout << " a is " << a << endl;
    cout << " b is " << b << endl;
    long long m = min(a,b);
    cout << " m is " << m << endl;
    long long and = min(m * n + m * 2LL * n, w);
    printf("%lld", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: The post is not valid C code.

Comment: Conversion of `long long` to `float` certainly loses precision for large values.

Answer (score 1):

The `b` variable cannot hold a floating point number since it is an integer. Not only your conversion to `float` happens too late, but you store the result in an integer variable. How could you expect something else than a integer result ?

```
float b = ((float)arr[n])/2.f;
```

Would give better results.

Answer (score 0):

The result of:

```
arr[n] / 2
```

is an integer expression, since both operands are integers. Therefore, it performs integer division, and you lose the precision you need. Converting the (integer) result to `float` afterwards will not help, because the precision is just *not there*.

To obtain the precision you need, make both operands `float`s before dividing:

```
float b = (float) arr[n] / 2.f;
```

Comment: Surely only one needs to be a float? I often do things like `arr[n] / 2.0` in order to coerce the expression to floating point. (and now I'm wondering what the default precision is without a literal suffix)

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid truncated integer division in this code?

Scale values by 2 and only divide by 2 in the end.

```
int main(void) {
    long long n,w;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &w);
    long long arr[2*n];
    for(long long i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
    {
      scanf("%lld", &arr[i]);
    }
    sort(arr,arr+2*n);

    long long a2 = arr[0]*2;
    long long b2 = arr[n];


    printf("a*2 %lld\n",  a2);
    printf("b*2 %lld\n",  b2);
    long long m2 = min(a2,b2);
    printf("m*2 %lld\n",  m2);

    long long ans2 = min(m2 * n + m2 * 2LL * n, w*2);
    printf("ans*2 %lld\n",  ans);
    printf("ans %lld.%d\n",  ans2/2, abs(ans%2)*5);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: In C, make certain `long long min(long long a, long long b)` has that signature.